# Vim copy and paste line with a search and replace

Tags: vim

Say I've written code that references the x dimension. What is the best way to get vim to duplicate a line of code replacing all references to x to y and to z (best being the most clear method).

Input:

```
length_x = X_vec.dot(X_vec)**.5
```

Desired Output:

```
length_x = X_vec.dot(X_vec)**.5
length_y = Y_vec.dot(Y_vec)**.5
length_z = Z_vec.dot(Z_vec)**.5
```

Here's my best so far.

```
function SwitchXtoYZ()
  :normal yy
  :normal p
  :normal! V
  :s/X/Y/ge
  :normal! V
  :s/x/y/ge
  :normal p
  :normal! V
  :s/X/Z/ge
  :normal! V
  :s/x/z/ge
endfunction

command XtoYZ exec SwitchXtoYZ() | :normal `.
```

It works, but I feel this is not very vim-y. Bonus points if the cursor returns to where it was before the command XtoYZ was issued (it currently goes the beginning of the second inserted line).

Comment: Would you consider a macro more vim-y?  If so you could record this:  `Y2p:s/x/y/ge^Mj:s/x/z/ge^Mj0`

Comment: @Jeff For me that generates two pasted lines and leaves an open command with `:s/x/y/ge^Mj:s/x/z/ge^Mj0` entered for execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function to do that, a macro would be fine for your requirement. Also you can define a macro in your vimrc too, if you like, so that you can have it everytime you open vim.

here is the macro:

```
qqv<Esc>Y2p:s/x/y/gi<Enter>n:s//z/gi<Enter>`<q
```

so it was recorded and saved in register `q`, you can `@q` to replay it.

explain it a little:

```
qq               " start recording into q
v<esc>           " enter visual mode and exit. to let `< work
Y2p              " yank current line and paste twice below
:s/x/y/gi<Enter> " x->y sub, case insensitive
n                " go to next x (here we could use j too)
:s//z/gi<Enter>  " do another sub x->z
`<               " back to the old cursor position
q                " end recording
```

if you want to `X->Y` and `x->y`, just remove the `i` flag and add two more `:s`

Comment: Thanks; a macro would mean fewer keystrokes. Can you provide an example of setting this in one's .vimrc? From [this Wikia page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros#Saving_a_macro) it seems that the carriage returns are problematic i.e. I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @vgm64 E.g, in your vimrc, `let @q=':echo "hello"<ctrl-v><enter>'`

Comment: A macro ties up one of your registers; in this case, the `@q` register.  If you yank into that register, or record another macro into it, then you lose this one.  Neither a command nor a map has this disadvantage, not to mention the problem with entering `<Enter>`.

Comment: @benjifisher I agree with u.

Comment: @Kent For completeness, I'd include a full description of putting the macro in a vimrc. As it stands, your answer is not clear about inserting literals versus actually typing out `<Enter>` or `<ctrl-v>`. A `let @q='v^[Y2p:s/X/Y/ge^M:s/x/y/ge^Mn:s/X/Z/ge^M:s/x/z/ge^M`<q'` would help (note changes for capitalization).

Comment: `let @q='v^[Y2p:s/X/Y/ge^M:s/x/y/ge^Mn:s/X/Z/ge^M:s/x/z/ge^M\`<'` rather. I had a trailing `q` and the premature formatting close rendered another tick.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>:</kbd> at the beginning of each line is optional, as are the `:normal! V` lines.

You are leveraging the Normal commands that you know, which is a good way to start, but IMHO you get cleaner code if you use more Command-mode (ex) commands and functions.  I would do something like this:

```
function! SwitchXtoYZ()
  let save_cursor = getpos(".")
  copy .
  s/X/Y/ge
  s/x/y/ge
  -copy .
  s/X/Z/ge
  s/x/z/ge
  call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfun
command! XtoYZ call SwitchXtoYZ()

:help function-list
:help getpos()
:help :call
:help :exec
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, @benjifisher. The clutter was half left over from trying to use a `command` implementation instead of a `function` and half because I didn't know any better. FWIW, I purposely had the capital letter replacements before the lowercase because I use `ignorecase`/`smartcase` so `X` would be replaced by `y` otherwise.

Comment: @vgm64:  Good point about the '*case' options.  I edited my answer to replace the uppercase letters first.  Do not forget to reward useful answers:  accept the one you like best, and vote up as many as you think are useful.